# Alternative test to paired t-test?

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, bootstrap, small-sample, paired-data

I need to compare data from paired groups, but my distributions are non-normal, and my sample size is small. Are there any tests I could apply?

I've been looking into non-parametric alternatives like WMW, but I don't know if it applies to paired groups. On a time crunch, and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Comment: For a paired t-test, the assumption is that the differences are normally distributed.

Comment: An alternative to signed-rank test would be to go for the one-sample permutation t-test.

Comment: If the distribution of the difference is not symmetric, use sign test.